# C# SQL query - try to use sum(weekly_slot) FROM group by

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to sum `weekly_slot` according to `Teacher_Name` from `GroupOdd` dbtable, however I am getting 10 values for all row. Appreciate if can correct me. Beside that, how to update `GroupOdd` dbtable to sort according to larger `sum_weekly_slot` first? 
Thanks.

```
cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd2 = dbConnect.CreateCommand();
//cmd2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM GroupOdd";
//cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Sum(Weekly_Slot) AS Sum_Weekly_Slot FROM GroupOdd group by Teacher_Name";
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
SQLiteDataAdapter da2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);
da2.Fill(dt2);
foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
{
    //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO GroupOdd (Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject, Weekly_Slot, Balance_Slot) VALUES (@Teacher_Name, @Standard, @Subject, @Weekly_Slot, @Balance_Slot)";
    cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE GroupOdd SET Sum_Weekly_Slot = @Sum_Weekly_Slot";
    //cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sum_Weekly_Slot", dr2["Sum(Weekly_Slot)"].ToString());
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sum_Weekly_Slot", dr2["Sum_Weekly_Slot"].ToString());
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a GROUP BY clause with the MAX aggregate function:

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

Than Update it accordingly.

IF

```
Sum(Weekly_Slot);
```

is not what u looking for

try

```
Count(Weekly_Slot)
```

Comment: Solved it with following: cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Teacher_Name, Sum(Weekly_Slot) FROM GroupOdd GROUP BY Teacher_Name"; cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE GroupOdd SET Sum_Weekly_Slot = @Sum_Weekly_Slot WHERE Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name"; cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr2["Teacher_Name"].ToString()); cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sum_Weekly_Slot", dr2["Sum(Weekly_Slot)"].ToString()); But how can I update the GroupOdd table to be sort by Sum_Weekly_Slot ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Teacher_Name, Sum(Weekly_Slot) AS Sum_Weekly_Slot FROM GroupOdd 
group by Teacher_Name order by Sum(Weekly_Slot) desc
```

Check the Teacher_Names are unique, else try to use an Id (TeacherId) for Teachers. The order by `Sum(Weekly_Slot) desc` should sort the table by largest first.

Comment: Don't have value from SELECT Teacher_Name, Sum(Weekly_Slot) AS Sum_Weekly_Slot FROM GroupOdd 
group by Teacher_Name order by Sum(Weekly_Slot) desc.

Comment: Solved it with following:

cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Teacher_Name, Sum(Weekly_Slot) FROM GroupOdd GROUP BY Teacher_Name";
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE GroupOdd SET Sum_Weekly_Slot = @Sum_Weekly_Slot WHERE Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr2["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sum_Weekly_Slot", dr2["Sum(Weekly_Slot)"].ToString());


But how can I update the GroupOdd table to be sort by Sum_Weekly_Slot ? Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to physically sort the table.?
You can always read the data from the table with order by clause so that you will always get the resultset in sorted order.

Select * From  GroupOdd order by Sum_Weekly_Slot desc